# Why can't I import this my own React Native file(WelcomeScreen.js) into my App.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm pretty new to React Native so please go easy on me.

I'm trying to import my WelocomeScreen.js file into my App.js file. What it's suppose to do is show a background image when WelcomeScreen.js is ran. However, I keep getting this error.[image] Here is my WelcomeScreen.js code:

```
import { StyleSheet, } from 'react-native-web';
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';

function WelcomeScreen(props) {
    return (
        <ImageBackground styles={styles.background} source={require("../background.jpg")}></ImageBackground>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        flex: 1, 
    }
})

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

This is my App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { WelcomeScreen } from './app/assets/screens/WelcomeScreen';

export default function App() {
    return (
      <WelcomeScreen></WelcomeScreen>
    );
}
```

This is the tutorial I'm following(time @ 1:47:10): [link](https://youtu.be/0-S5a0eXPoc)

And lastly my directory:

[image]

Like I said I'm still a pretty new developer but this issue has been giving me problems for a couple days. If you need any more info, I'll be active the next couple of hours. If there's any other errors(which there probably is) or ways to make my code cleaner, please just let me know.

Comment: I have answered your question, please mark it as answered, if it worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing **default export** for WelcomeScreen

Instead of this

`import {WelcomeScreen} from '.location'`

Do

`import WelcomeScreen from '.location'`

Comment: That still doesn't work. I got an error saying `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'style.width')`

Comment: Where are  you referring style.width ? Which file is that? Change `style.width` to `styles.width`

Comment: One suggestion, don't use background as a key for styles object, name the keys line container or sidebar, something like that, naming background and width can cause some undefined behaviour. And the code will look much more readable.

Comment: Well I'm not getting any errors but the image isn't show up, just a white screen

Comment: That is actually related to your styles,  this issue in this question has been solved